# Diff tool for the whole OS

Tags: windows

I vaguely remember remember reading about a (new?) tool that can diff a computer. I think it was from Microsoft aimed at developers and it could find difference in files, file versions, registry keys, etc.

Now we need this tool for a project where an installer has gone bad.

Anyone know what tool it is? Or similar tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try the beta of Microsoft's

> **[Attack Surface Analyzer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e068c224-9d6d-4bf4-aab8-f7352a5e7d45&displaylang=en)**

Answer (score 0):

I also found this comercial product: http://www.blueproject.ro/systracer